# Same reputation for documentation and document improvement?

Tags: discussion, documentation, reputation, quality-improvement

I have observed there is similar reputation (+2) for

1. Writing the document and
2. Improving the document.

Ideally the document author spends lot of time to investigate and write a nice document. Also some times it requires writing a fresh program and taking screenshots of it etc... to place the snips in document. So the author end up getting reputation +2.

Now a person who kindly spend the time to improve the document, some times just a spelling mistake is corrected hardly and changes are published. They end up getting reputation +2 .. Which takes a minute of time to improve the content in many cases.

I feel the weight of reputation for the fresh document writer should be more than +2 in this case.

Comment: Is this not addressed by the fact that adding an example means you get +5 rep for each upvote on it forever? Editors have to put in more than just a couple spelling corrections to get even +1 for each example upvote.

Comment: Also i dont understand why down vote for this question. Is it a mistake to ask?

Comment: In this case, probably "lack of of research" (shows in the tooltip on the downvote arrow). There are many questions about reputation on Documentation; see the Related sidebar for some of them.

Comment: My question is about why equal reputation! ? Yes, i did research before posting. If you find this duplicate, you can paste the link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight of the "fresh document writer" is *much* more than +2. Creating a topic or example automatically makes the creator a major contributor to it, meaning:

- They get +5 rep every time it gets cited by an upvoted answer.
- They get +5 rep every time it gets upvoted.

Users improving documentation can achieve this too—but they need to add 350 or more characters, not including formatting and whitespace, and they can also *lose* this status when the topic or example is rolled back.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Your answer grabs my attention. But i every time see down votes to many questions that are asked in Meta. Not to mention, It looks wrong to ask questions here!

Comment: @user why is "wrong" to post questions on Meta? Votes on Meta don't affect your reputation. Questions that are downvoted a lot are generally just really, really bad feature requests.